# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "react"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, react-router

starting with, i am a beginner in React with Rails and trying things out. I am currently working with routing and i'm not sure where i'm going wrong. Please guide me.

I have a container folder with UserWorld.jsx file. Its content are as follows:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import User from '../containers/User';

// Simple example of a React "smart" component
export default class UserWorld extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    // How to set initial state in ES6 class syntax
    // https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes
    this.state = { users: this.props.data
    };
  }
  render() {
    var userNodes = this.state.users.map(function(user) {
      return (
          <User key={user.id} first_name={user.first_name} last_name={user.last_name} email={user.email} city={user.city} address={user.address} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>City</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {userNodes}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, i wish to add a link and i'm including

`import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router'`

However this gives me an error in the console as follows:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "react"
Exception in rendering!
message: Could not find component registered with name UserWorldApp. Registered component names include [ HelloWorldApp ]. Maybe you forgot to register the component?
```

Now i have no clue about whats happening here. I would be obliged if someone could help me out here. Also, if i can get references for the same. I am facing trouble with the different syntax that are found all around.

**Update:**

I see that the error is appearing in the `var _react = require('react');` line in the Router.js in react-router folder in the node_modules folder.

I get this in console:

```
ERROR in ../~/react-router/lib/Router.js
18:03:09 client.1 | Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'imports' in /Users/c193/Documents/React/test-react-on-rails/node_modules/react-router/lib
18:03:09 client.1 |  @ ../~/react-router/lib/Router.js 19:13-29
```

P.S: All the docs and articles i read are way too technical for me to understand and i only understand bits and pieces of it. Its just been two weeks since i started.

Comment: Did you install `react`? Do you have a `package.json` file?

Comment: Yes, i have `package.json` file and i installed react and react-router using `npm i react react-dom react-router --save` and webpack using `npm i webpack webpack-dev-server babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save-dev`

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on because you have so many error messages in play. For example, you posted this error message: `Error: Cannot resolve module 'imports'`. It's not clear how that relates to the `Cannot find module "react"` error. React and React Router are in the same `node_modules/`, right?

Comment: Try clearing the cache. rm -rf node_modules, npm cache clear, and npm install.

Comment: Are you transpiling your code with babel? `import` is not supported out of the box.

Comment: @JMM, Yes, both the react and the react-router are present in the same folder (npm_modules).

Comment: @Vijay, i cleared the cache as well but the error persists.

Comment: @MarioTacke, i couldn't understand you, can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, but with "react-router" instead of "react." Check the `package.json` in the `client` directory, and if anything's missing, add it manually and run `npm install` from that directory. That solved the issue for me, although as somebody commented, you probably have a few other issues here as well.

I don't think running `npm install react-router --save` from the root project directory is a good idea, because React on Rails uses yarn, so the only thing in the `node_modules` directory in the main project folder should be a `.yarn.integrity` file. Everything you need for React should be in the `package.json` file and `node_modules` directory in the `client` folder, so check if something's missing from there.

Here's what their `client/package.json` looks like in the tutorial: https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/blob/master/client/package.json

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what the problem was or what i missed. However, in a completely new project, I ran `npm install react-router --save`. I put `import { Link } from 'react-router/lib/Link';` in my react component. Restarted the server and i was good to go. I did these same steps in my previous app an it somehow didn't work for me. Anyways, i don't know what i was missing but the problem is solved for now.

P.S: I'm now facing a new issue regarding this and opening a new question for the same.

Thank you anyways people. :)